# Poor predictions from lm.ridge?

Tags: r, ridge-regression

I don't understand why predictions from `lm.ridge()` are so far out, when using the "best" lambda, based upon GCV. Can anyone help me to obtain better predictions? Or, at least, does anyone have a good ridge example with a simple explanation of the results?

Below is my R code for wine quality data (from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv):

```
library(MASS)
wine_all <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv", sep=";", header = T)
#wine_all <- read.table("winequality-red.csv", sep=";", header = T)
wine_train <- wine_all[1:1400,]
wine_test <- wine_all[-(1:1400),]

train.lm <- lm.ridge(quality~., wine_train, lambda = seq(0, 100, 0.1))
plot(x=train.lm$lambda, y=train.lm$GCV)

pred.test <- scale(wine_test[,1:11], center = F, scale = train.lm$scales) %*% train.lm$coef[, which.min(train.lm$GCV)] + train.lm$ym

pred.all <-  scale(wine_all[,1:11], center = F, scale = train.lm$scales) %*% train.lm$coef[, which.min(train.lm$GCV)] + train.lm$ym
cor(wine_test[, 12], pred.test)^2
cor(wine_all[, 12], pred.all)^2
```

Answer (score 6):

The results are comparable to those of a standard regression.
I guess this is not a situation in which ridge regression improves the estimators: 
the number of variables is small compared to the number of observations, and
there are no colinearity problems.

```
pairs(wine_train,gap=0)
d <- cbind(
  wine_test[, 12], pred.test, 
  predict( lm(quality~., wine_train), wine_test )
)
pairs(d, gap=0 )
cor(d)
```

The scale of your forecasts is wrong, however: you need `center=TRUE`.